# Taking Twilio calls in a new Popup window

Tags: websocket, twilio

I am facing a scenario where live Twilio call gets dropped, if the browser window in which call is received is reloaded. Is there a way to overcome this set-back without affecting the live calls?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio Evangelist here.

Based on your question, I assume you are using the Twilio Client JavaScript SDK?  If that is indeed the case, then unfortunately, if the page thats hosting the SDK gets reloaded the connection between the browser and Twilio will drop since the browser is reloading everything, including the JavaScript SDK.

There are a couple of different techniques I can think of off the top of my head that you can use to help avoid page reloads, and another idea that could help you recover a call where the connection to the browser has dropped because of a page reload.  A lot of this is going to depend on your specific app and the experience you are trying to create for your users.

So to help avoid having to reload the page:

1) Use AJAX requests to your server in order to avoid page reloads.  If your page includes content like a form, or you want to update the page content with data form the server, you can look using AJAX requests to the server instead of a normal full page postback to submit the form, or to retrieve the data form the server.  This would help in avoiding having to reload the entire page in those two scenarios.

2) Use an iFrame to host your page content, and then put the Twilio SDK in the parent page (the one that defined the iFrame).  This would let you reload the content hosted in the iframe, without having to reload the entire host page, avoiding a reload the the Twilio library.  The downside to this is that communicating between content in an iframe and its host can get really messy fast.

Neither of these two techniques is fool-proof.  Obviously a user can always just hit the refresh button on their browser, and thats going to cause the connection to drop.

In a case where the page does get reloaded, and the connection from Twilio to the browser gets dropped, one idea is to leverage Twilios  capability to help reconnect the caller together.  When a user calls your twilio phone number, instead of connecting them directly to the Twilio Client running in the browser (by dialing a client with `<Client>`), instead dial that caller into a conference `<Conference>`, and then have the browser client connect into that same conference.  The benefit to that is if the browser disconnects, the original caller won't get hung up on, they will still be sitting in the conference room.  As long as you've saved the Conference SID or name, you can have the browser client reconnect to that conference.

Hope that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Any new developments in the last 7 years that would allow the call to persist between page loads? The conference call suggestion is the least hacky solution, but still not ideal. I'd prefer to store the connection to Twilio within the browser itself somehow, avoiding the disconnect on page-load.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to overcome this?